# How make a Sub to Address a [New Thread] Call?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a **BackgroundWorker** routine that performs a lot of things and call *ThreadSafe* functions to update UI controls. In some points of that routine I call some subroutines to write log information into a SQL table, using the Parallel Library to make them in another Thread. It´s functioning like a charm.

The threaded LOG calls are like this, where **Log_Compressed_File()** is a subroutine:

```
Dim Log_Threaded as Thread = New Thread(Sub() Log_Compressed_File(Username, UserAreaCode, Filename))
Log_Threaded.IsBackground = False
Log_Threaded.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
Log_Threaded.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.MTA)
Log_Threaded.Start
```

As shown above, each *log* call is made using 5 lines of code, defining the new thread itself and some important parameters.

My questions are:

1) **can I produce a Sub to address these calls, trying to reduce the lines of the main routine?**

Just to make it clear: I have more than 35 LOG calls within the main routine and, if each one would utilize 5 lines of code, I will have 175 lines, when I could have only the original 35 calls to a new subroutine that could address the new thread.

2) **Can I call that subroutine from within the *BackgroundWorker* without to call a delegate function (ThreadSafe) like I use in UI updates?**

The function like shown above can be performed within the *BackgroundWorker* without to a DELEGATE function (the LOG_COMPRESSED_FILE is a normal Sub, not a Delegate call).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.  Just write a method with the same three parameters as your `Log_Compressed_File` method and then put that code into that method.
2. Yes.  Do you understand why you need to use a delegate at all?  The point is that you cannot access the `Handle` of a control on any thread other than the one it was created on.  Invoking a delegate ensures that code accessing the control's `Handle` is executed on the correct thread.  If you're not accessing a control then there's no `Handle` so why would it matter what thread you execute the code on?